# Como alterar a cor e o posicionamento de duas Labels Lado a lado em XAML?

Tags: xaml, label, text

```
    <Label>
            <Label.FormattedText>
                <FormattedString>
                    <Span Text="R$"
                          FontAttributes="Bold"
                          FontSize="Large"/>
                    <Span x:Name="CalculoParcial"
                          FontAttributes="Bold"
                          FontSize="Large"/>
                </FormattedString>
            </Label.FormattedText>
        </Label>
```

Comment: `XAML` do [tag:xamarin.forms] ou do [tag:wpf]?

Comment: Perdão, XAML do Xamarin Forms

Comment: No código que você compartilhou você tem somente 1 label com duas partes como `FormattedString`. Nesse caso não dá para mudar posicionamento, somente a formatação.